# Validate both email id and phone number in one text field in mvc 4

Tags: c#, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a signup form. In the form I need to validate both email id and phone number in the same text box field. Is it possible in MVC 4?

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: You would need to write your own validation attribute.

Comment: Check to see if the entry is a valid email address, if so use it, if not check if it's a valid phone number. You'll have to roll your own logic to achieve this though.

Comment: Thanks @stephen i got the idea and implement sucessfully

Answer (score 1):

Finally I had implement custom validation to achieve the mobile number and email id validations in one text box.

**Sample Code**

```
public class customvalidation : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                string email = value.ToString();
                if (Regex.IsMatch(email, @"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
                else if (Regex.IsMatch(email, @"(\d*-)?\d{10}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
                else
                {
                    return new ValidationResult("Invalid EmailID or Mobile Number");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult("" + validationContext.DisplayName + "is required");
            }
            //return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like for the first key up event in your textbox you can check whether it begins with a number or a character, based on the result you can validate whether its Email id or phone number

```
$("#TextboxID").keyup(function(){
var value=$("#TextboxID").val();
//Regex for mobile number
var phoneNumber = ^[0-9]{1};

//Regex for Email Id
var Email= ^[a-zA-Z]{1};

//Now in if condition you can check whether it begins with a number or a character.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way using regular expression in fluent validation, I think you can do it like this:

```
    public UserLoginValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(user => user.EmailOrPhone).NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("Bu alan boş bırakılamaz.");
        RuleFor(user => user.EmailOrPhone).Must(IsValidEmailOrTelephone).WithMessage("Format geçerli değil.");

        RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotNull().NotEmpty();
    }
    bool IsValidEmailOrTelephone(string emailOrPhone)
    {
        bool phone = Regex.IsMatch(emailOrPhone, @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        bool email = Regex.IsMatch(emailOrPhone, @"((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}");
        return phone || email;
    }
```